# MonadError instance for a Free Monad

Tags: haskell, typeclass, free-monad, overlapping-instances

I have created a very useful Free Monad out of a sum data type. That abstracts access to a persistent data store:

```
data DataStoreF next = 
     Create    Asset                           ( String -> next)
  |  Read      String                          ( Asset  -> next)
  |  Update    Asset                           ( Bool   -> next)
  |  UpdateAll [Asset]                         ( Bool   -> next)
  |  Delete    Asset                           ( Bool   -> next)
  |  [...] -- etc. etc.
  |  Error     String

type DataStore = Free DataStoreF
```

I would like to make `DataStore` an instance of `MonadError` with the error message handled as `(Free (Error str))`:

```
instance MonadError String DataStore where
  throwError str = errorDS str
  catchError (Free (ErrorDS str)) f = f str
  catchError x _ = x
```

But I am running into Overlapping Instances errors.

What is the proper way to make the `DataStore` monad and instance of `MonadError`?

Comment: You can wrap it in a `newtype` and control the instances yourself. I don't think there's a cleaner way to do it. The instances for `FreeT` assume you won't be providing any of the mtl classes provided by other transformers.

Comment: How is this different from the last line of the first code block?

Comment: @JohnF.Miller In your example, `DataStore` is just a type alias, not a `newtype`, which gives you all of `Free`’s instances automatically. However, if you make it a `newtype` instead, you can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to pick and choose which instances you want to inherit, and you can define your own `MonadError` instance.

Comment: You could just enable overlapping instances (or add the `{-# OVERLAPS #-}` pragma to your instance, if you have a sufficiently recent GHC version). With this, e.g. `throwError undefined :: DataStore ()` would use your instance. Unless you are for some reason unwilling to use this feature, this is certainly the simplest solution (the addition of a single line fixes your problem).

Comment: @user2407038 that solved my problem without any large rewrite! (We'll see if the enchanted brooms flood my basement later) If you put write this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: By the way, your definition of `catchError` seems dubious to me; I'd expect that `catchError` would also catch errors that aren't the first step taken by the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance and the instance given by the library:

```
instance (Functor m, MonadError e m) => MonadError e (Free m)
```

are indeed overlapping, but this does not mean that they are incompatible. Note that the above instance is 'more general' in a sense than yours - any type which would match your instance would match this one. When one uses the `OverlappingInstances` extension (or with modern GHC, an `{-# OVERLAP{S/PING/PABLE} #-}` pragma), instances may overlap, and the most specific (*least* general) instance will be used.

Without the extension, e.g. `throwError "x" :: DataStore ()` gives the type error:

```
* Overlapping instances for MonadError [Char] (Free DataStoreF)
    arising from a use of `throwError'
  Matching instances:
    instance [safe] (Functor m, MonadError e m) =>
                    MonadError e (Free m)
      -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Free'
    instance [safe] MonadError String DataStore
```

but with the addition of a pragma

```
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} 
  MonadError String DataStore where
```

the expression `throwError "x" :: DataStore ()` *still* matches both instances, but since one is more specific than the other (the one you wrote) it is selected:

```
>throwError "x" :: DataStore ()
Free (Error "x")
```

Comment: To future readers: Alexis King's answer is probably the more appropriate choice in an ideal world, and should be strongly considered before using a somewhat suspect language extension like `{-# OVERLAPS #-}`, but this so elegantly and quickly addressed my issue in an already extensive code base that I have chosen it as my accepted answer. Thank you to both (as of 2016-08-06) of you who responded.

Answer (score 5):

The `Free` type already provides a `MonadError` instance for *all* free monads:

```
instance (Functor m, MonadError e m) => MonadError e (Free m) where { ... }
```

When you write `type DataStore = ...`, you are simply defining a *type alias*, which is basically a type-level macro. All uses of the `DataStore` type are replaced with its definition. This means that using `DataStore` is indistinguishable from using `Free DataStoreF` directly, so when you do this:

```
instance MonadError String DataStore where { ... }
```

…you are actually doing this:

```
instance MonadError String (Free DataStoreF) where { ... }
```

…and that conflicts with the instance defined above.

To circumvent that, you should define a `newtype` to produce an entirely fresh type that can have its own instances on it, unrelated to the ones defined on `Free`. If you use the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension, you can avoid a lot of the boilerplate that would otherwise be required by a separate `newtype`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving -}

data DataStoreF next = ...

newtype DataStore a = DataStore (Free DataStoreF a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance MonadError String DataStore where { ... }
```

This should avoid the overlapping instance problem without the need to write out all the `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances manually.

Comment: What does the builtin instance do?  I looked at it, but I cannot fulfill the requirement that `DataStoreF` be an `MonadError` because it is in fact not a monad.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller The default instance just says that `Free` is a [monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) that happens to preserve `MonadError`.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller Right, it only works if `DataStoreF` is already a monad, which sort of defeats the whole purpose of the common use-case for using `Free`. It’s not much of an issue, though, given that a `newtype` works just as well.

Comment: @AlexisKing, ok, I'm just not looking forward to adding the `newtype` annotation to three different interpreters + helper functions *  16 instructions each.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller Yeah, it’s a little syntactically inconvenient. In general, I would avoid type aliases in Haskell—they tend to cause more problems than they solve, and they don’t really add any safety. Almost always prefer `newtype`s.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller You shouldn't have to unpack the `newtype` for every case of your base functor! If your interpreters work [compositionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality) you should be able to use [`iterM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#v:iterM) to tear down your free monad (a bit like [`cata`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/2984/recursion-schemes/10137/folding-up-a-structure-one-layer-at-a-time)) and write an algebra that doesn't worry about the free monad.

Comment: Actually the requirement is that the base monad (here `Identity`) needs to be an instance of `MonadError`. OP might be able to use a free monad transformer on an error monad rather than defining the `Error` action as part of `DataStoreF`.